Limiting API calls with Alpha vantage on React
I am trying to limit the number of API calls being made when fetching data from Alpha Vantage. So far I've tried using throttling and debouncing, I also tried using the setInterval() method inside a useEffect, which were to no use as when running the react app it makes a lot of API calls. How can I change these simple lines so that it only makes one API call per a set amount of time:
const fetchData = async (symbol) => {
  const API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";
  var URL = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=${symbol}&interval=5min&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
  const response = await fetch(URL);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

I tried a different approach to getting the data, not sure if its relevant.
 let alphavantage = async () => {
    try {
      fetch(URL)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setNum(num + 1);
          console.log("Number of API calls made: ", num);
          setData(data);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error fetching data: ", error);
    }
  };

Thank you!

this is how I did it
Wait for 0 minutes before the next request to avoid API limits
            time.sleep(300)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information.
Please edit to add further details,
such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.
You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
